# draw line in actionscript 3 without using the draw API?

Tags: actionscript-3, movieclip, bitmapdata

I need to be able to draw a thick patterend line between 2 points in AS3, I can't use the draw API because it doesn't all me to actually put detail (pattern etc) into the thickness of the line, I thought about perhaps using the line to create a bitmap version and then using that as a mask, but I remember many years ago seeing some examples that use a movieclip as a source for a line, but I can't find examples of that now at all, any ideas?

I've attached an example image of how I want the line to look.[image]

Answer (score 3):

I suspect [`Graphics.lineBitmapStyle()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Graphics.html#lineBitmapStyle%28%29) will do the trick. If you want to use a `Sprite` or `MovieClip` as the source, you'll have to [`draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) it to a `BitmapData` first. The example code on that later link should get you up and running with that.

Comment: thanks, I got that working, but it gives a mask like effect, which after seeing it, is not what I want, I need it to look like I'm stretching out a line which has a pattern (movieclip) on it, not like I'm just moving a line-mask around over the top of a pattern, which is what lineBitmapStyle gives you.

Comment: If you expand your original question to cover how you want it to look it will be a lot easier to give pointers.